# rvm symlink to gems for default ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, symlink

I've noticed that rvm creates a symlink to the default ruby installation in `~/.rvm/rubies/default`. But I can't find a symlink for the gems for the default ruby installation; `~/.rvm/gems/default` does not exist.

Is this symlink hidden somewhere? I've searched through the `~/.rvm` directory with `find ~/.rvm -name 'default'`, and the closest thing I've found is `~/.rvm/wrappers/default`, which appears to contain `ruby` and `gem` and all the gems I've installed, but they are called with wrapper scripts.

This seems effectively equivalent to what I want. Is it?

Ideally, I think I would like a symlink to a subdirectory of `~/.rvm/gems`.

The reason I want this is so I can tell an IDE where to find my gems without hard-coding the version number of the current ruby, and preferably without relying on running rvm in the IDE or relying on the IDE inheriting the environment variables of a shell that ran rvm.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of creating an app specific bundle for your applications with rvm? Most Ruby IDEs recognize this configuration and this makes everything easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is managed through an environment variable called GEM_PATH, not at a symlink:

```
$ echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/mikek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@project:/Users/mikek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
```

I believe the issue is that if it were just a single symlink it couldn't account for RVM's global gemset available to all other gemsets you associate with that ruby as well as the project-based gemsets.